# Put images next to each other using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on an assignment and ran into a bit of a problem. I am trying to put images next to each other using CSS. But it does not seem to work. I am using semantic HTML, which means for the two images I am using the `<figure>` tag. I will show example of the code I have:

```css
.blitz {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}

figcaption {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: gray;
}

.rum {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img class="blitz" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="Berry Blitz">
  <figcaption>Fall Berry Blitz Tea</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img class="rum" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-spiced-rum.jpg" alt="Spiced Rum">
  <figcaption>Spiced Rum Teat</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `figure` elements inside of a `div` and set that to display as `flex`. See below:

```css
div {
  display:flex;
}
img {
  max-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <figure>
    <img class= "blitz" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="Berry Blitz">
    <figcaption>Fall Berry Blitz Tea</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img class="rum" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-spiced-rum.jpg" alt="Spiced Rum">
    <figcaption>Spiced Rum Teat</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```